# Could not access bucket Code = -13000 Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload user information to the firebase server. I have followed the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files) provided by google to try to do so but i am getting an error for unknown reasons.

Here is how i carry out the upload task

```
        NSMutableDictionary *userdata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [userdata setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
        [userdata setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
        [userdata setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
        [userdata setObject:handphoneNumber forKey:@"HPNO"];

        [[FIRAuth auth] createUserWithEmail:email password:password completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (user) {

                NSString *storageUrl = [FIRApp defaultApp].options.storageBucket;
                self.storageRef = [[FIRStorage storage] referenceForURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"gs://%@", storageUrl]];
                NSString *usrstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userdata];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:usrstring];
                FIRStorageReference *userRef = [self.storageRef child:usrstring];
                FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask = [userRef putData:data
                                                            metadata:nil
                                                            completion:^(FIRStorageMetadata * metadata, NSError * error) {
                                                                if (error) {
                                                                    NSLog(@"ERROR -- %@",error);
                                                                }
                                                            }];
                }
        }];
```

During runtime when the task is being carried out, i face this in the console

```
Cannot get file size: (null)
  (null)
2017-02-15 01:38:09.772 E-Learning[2280:92867] ERROR -- Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={object={
    HPNO = 123123;
    email = "test@gmail.com";
    name = test;
    username = test;
}, bucket=firebase-testrun8519.appspot.com, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "An internal error has occurred.  Could not access bucket firebase-testrun8519.appspot.com"
  }
}, data=<7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 20202022 636f6465 223a2035 30302c0a 20202020 226d6573 73616765 223a2022 416e2069 6e746572 6e616c20 6572726f 72206861 73206f63 63757272 65642e20 20436f75 6c64206e 6f742061 63636573 73206275 636b6574 20666972 65626173 652d656c 6561726e 696e6773 672e6170 7073706f 742e636f 6d220a20 207d0a7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=com.google.HTTPStatus, ResponseErrorCode=500}
```

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would clean up the code to change:

```
NSString *storageUrl = [FIRApp defaultApp].options.storageBucket;
self.storageRef = [[FIRStorage storage] referenceForURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"gs://%@", storageUrl]];
```

To be:

```
self.storageRef = [[FIRStorage storage] reference];
```

Additionally, `dataWithContentsOfFile:` takes a string representing the path to a file on disk, not a string you want to upload. Instead you want to use `NSString dataUsingEncoding:` (I recommend using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`). See [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416696-datausingencoding?language=objc) for more.